# How do I use the PHP constant __DIR__ with `header('LOCATION:'.__DIR__.'/file.php');` when using XAMPP on localhost Linux?

Tags: php, linux, xampp, localhost

`__DIR__` is giving me `/opt/lampp/htdocs/folder`. Since that is really my Linux filesystem location it will not redirect using `header('LOCATION:'.__DIR__.'/file.php');`. How do I make it so `__DIR__` won't go all the way to my Linux root and instead go to something more like `localhost/folder`? I'm guessing it's some kind of configuration thing, but I have no idea.

The reason I want to do this is so I can set a `const` that I can use for redirection based on where the future Client puts my PHP.

Comment: Something like `header('Location: /folder/file.php');`?

Comment: Can I just not use `__DIR__` like that? Is it only for include and require stuff? I can live with that, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it.

Comment: that's what `__DIR__` will do - give the full path ~ not really suitable for your purpose but useful in several situations not just `includes`

Comment: Thanks @ProfessorAbronsius. If that's just how it is then you can put that as the answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Right. `__DIR__` will give you a filesystem path. You could use indices from `$_SERVER` to assemble a complete servername, but just using `header('Location: /folder/file.php');` will do it.

Comment: ... which will also give you a filesystem path - also not suitable in your case. I was thinking more along the lines of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` and the likes

Comment: @brombeer I guess I'm just having a rough day. `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` gave me `localhost`. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gave me `/opt/lampp/htdocs`. So, not the answer I was looking for, but thanks for looking out.

Comment: What seems to be the problem right now? What are you trying to achieve? As stated, you can't use `__DIR__` or `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to redirect. You _can_ use something like `header('Location: /folder/file.php');` to redirect to `http://localhost:8000/folder/file.php` though, given that `http://localhost:8000` is your server.

Comment: The problem is, it depends on where a future Client will put my API folder, which has a specific file in it.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`? From [$_​SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php): "_The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root._"

Comment: Another option is a config.file. After (or during) install of your script, the client can set a value for let's say `$document_root` like `$document_root = '/var/www/whatever/folder';` pointing to the main folder of your app. Then all paths will be relative to this `$document_root` and you can use in your code something like `<a href='.$document_root.'/api` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
$dir = preg_replace('@^'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'@', '', __DIR__);
```

It looks like I can use that only on the same page I'm getting the `__DIR__` of, so it can't be made into a reusable function.

Therefore, as long as `$dir` is on the same page I'm using `header('LOCATION:'` on, I redirect like:

```
header('LOCATION:'.$dir.'/../folder/file.php');
```